# Remove duplicate SQL Join results

Tags: sql, postgresql

Okay, I and totally new to SQL so bear with me. I created a statement which I have the results I wanted but wanted get rid of duplicate results. What's a easy solution to this? Here is my statement

```
SELECT
    li.location,
    li.logistics_unit,
    li.item,
    li.company,
    li.item_desc,
    li.on_hand_qty,
    li.in_transit_qty,
    li.allocated_qty,
    li.lot,
    i.item_category3,
    location.locating_zone,
    location.location_subclass,
    i.item_category4
FROM
    location_inventory li
INNER JOIN item i ON li.item = i.item
INNER JOIN location l ON l.location = li.location
WHERE
    i.item_category3 = 'AS' AND
    li.warehouse = 'river' AND
    li.location NOT LIKE 'd%' AND
    li.location NOT LIKE 'stg%'
ORDER BY
    li.item asc
```

Comment: Generally duplicate results in a query like this are due to a logic or `join` problem.  I would investigate further (by looking at intermediate results) to be sure all the conditions are correct and complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident in your `JOIN` then `DISTINCT` should do the trick like so:

```
select DISTINCT
       location_inventory.location , 
       location_inventory.logistics_unit , 
       location_inventory.item , 
       location_inventory.company , 
       location_inventory.item_desc , 
       location_inventory.on_hand_qty , 
       location_inventory.in_transit_qty , 
       location_inventory.allocated_qty , 
       location_inventory.lot ,
       item.item_category3 , 
       location.locating_zone , 
       location.location_subclass , 
       item.item_category4
from location_inventory
INNER JOIN item
on location_inventory.item=item.item
INNER JOIN location
on location_inventory.location=location.location
where item.item_category3 = 'AS' and 
      location_inventory.warehouse = 'river' and 
      location_inventory.location not like 'd%' and 
      location_inventory.location not like 'stg%'
order by location_inventory.item asc
```

Comment: You are missing table alias `li`

Comment: @Dre basically if your JOINS are correct then DISTINCT is a the way to remove dupes. but like Gordon Lindoff said the issue could be with your JOIN but we cant tell unless we know what your data sets are. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that i.item and l.location are primary or unique keys, any duplicates you see are being caused by duplicate items in your location_inventory table.  That might or might not be what you want.

`SELECT DISTINCT` will only eliminate true duplicates (i.e. those where all of the selected columns are duplicate).  If that's what you want, use it.  Otherwise, you might need to make an inner select that uses SELECT DISTINCT to identify the columns in which you don't want duplicates, and join the results of the inner select back to the tables to pull out all the other data.

Comment: If you have two rows in `location_inventory` that have different values in other columns (e.g. `lot`) but the same value in `logistics_unit`, do you want to print one row or two?